# Electron build works locally but after code is committed to Github it breaks

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, electron

My electron build works locally when I run with node inside the terminal. I then commit the code to Github. Next I download the version of the app and get an error explaining that a node module is not found. I definitely installed because it works before committing to Github. Any idea why this would happen? Here is the package.json to show that the module is installed with the most recent version as of the time of this post.

Package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "12.1.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.1",
    "electron-winstaller": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "asar": "^3.0.3",
    "electron-store": "^6.0.0",
    "every-moment": "0.0.1",
    "node-notifier": "^8.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "update-electron-app": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=false --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . Look-Away --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=false --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Look Away\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . Look Away --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/1024x1024.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  }
}
```

[image: Image of error]

Comment: With due respect, your question should really be "Any **guesses** why?" - give us a link to your repo or share your `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I added the package.json

Comment: Have you run `npm install` after downloading it locally?

Comment: Because I'm running the packaged version I shouldn't have to right @myselfmiqdad? Isn't it a distributable version?

Comment: The only difference is the `prune` switch. Yes, the packaged version should work.

Comment: Darn... any idea what might be doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the version that was working before Github on a website where it could be downloaded and linked it to the repository.